# How to identify if stack in core-dump is reliable and local variables hold correct values

Tags: stack, mips, coredump

This query is to get the art of validating a stack in general. Below is an example of the problem which may help while giving some ideas.

I am dealing with a **MIPS core dump**, whose partial stack trace is below.

```
#2  0x7772027c in __assert13 (file=<optimized out>, line=<optimized out>, function=<optimized out>, failedexpr=<optimized out>) at /work.local/build/toolSpaces/tools01/E9-3-0/SW-NetBSD5/usr/src/lib/libc_r/../libc/gen/assert.c:61
#3  0x773baf3c in f10IpcSendWait (key=0x8f08, payload=0x76d9e318 "", len=0x274, tmout=0x3c, type=0xaf1, transaction=0xc0f) at f10IpcLib.c:2412
#4  0x77391d04 in cfgIpcSendWait (pkey=<optimized out>, cmdType=0x69, data=0x76d9e7a0, len=0x224, retStatus=<optimized out>) at f10CfgLib.c:751
#5  0x77391fc0 in f10CfgGetExact (pkey=0x1, usrData=0x784bb040) at f10CfgLib.c:554
#6  0x1002785c in f10GetBanner (pKey=0x8f08, bannerType=<optimized out>, sessionType=<optimized out>, sessionId=<optimized out>, bannerString=0x77b33000 <Address 0x77b33000 out of bounds>) at pamBannerHandler.c:123
#7  0x10040e40 in sshGetAuthBanner (banner=0x77b33000 <Address 0x77b33000 out of bounds>) at sshPamUtils.c:74
#8  0x10015b80 in userauth_banner () at auth2.c:176
#9  input_userauth_request (type=<optimized out>, seq=<optimized out>, ctxt=<optimized out>) at auth2.c:303
#10 0x76edbea0 in dispatch_run (mode=0x0, done=0x784bbb40, ctxt=0x784bb040) at dispatch.c:98
```

Here *userauth_banner*() calls *sshGetAuthBanner* () with a parameter **0x77b33000**. However, when I look into the local variable *banner* of userauth_banner() it shows me absolutely different value.

```
(gdb) p banner 
$20 = 0x1 <Address 0x1 out of bounds>
```

I understand that RISC parameters can be passed on stack - but what I can't get is how GDB shows the parameter as 0x77b33000. I guess that it is parameter of some other function called after *sshGetAuthBanner*() or a result of some other calculation or operation.

```
userauth_banner(void)
{               
        char *banner = NULL;
            if ((banner = (char *)xcalloc(2, 25600)) == NULL)
                goto done;
        sshGetAuthBanner(banner);
        if (!strlen(banner))
            goto done;
```

So, in all I want to understand, what should we look for, to ascertain if a stack is correct. Also, which value in the case discussed above is more reliable and why.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: The argument for `sshGetAuthBanner` ought to be in register `$a0` (i.e. `$4`).

Comment: @Michael - Yes, and I see that somehow it is in register s2.         (gdb) info register s2
s2: 0x77b33000

Comment: Perhaps it is related to the C compiler optimiser - what happens if you repeat this with a non optimised build?